# Column Show/Hide on Checkbox selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am working on column filter in .NET MVC project. my requirement is, in a dropdown control all table header column name will bind with the checkbox. By default, all option are selected. When I deselect from dropdown any option it reflects to table data and that column will not be shown.

I write some code but not able to implement checkbox functionality. Please help me. If jquery plugin is available that also helpful for me.

[JsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ggd0r4dz/2/)

Code

```
$("#myOptions").change(function() {
      selectedVal = $.trim($("#myOptions option:selected").text());
    var i = $("#myTable thead .headercell td:contains(" + selectedVal + ")").index() + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + i+ ')').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: what do you want to happened? i think it works as you wanted

Comment: May be [this](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri) can help or [Multi Select List with Checkboxes](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect.html)

Comment: i want to bind checkbox inside dropdown. multiple selection for show hide column

Comment: Jquery Select2 plugin can be used for this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to make multi select to easier: use `select2`:

```js
$("#myOptions").select2({
  tags: true
}).change(function() {
  var test = $("#myOptions").val();
  $("td").show();
  for (var j = 0, len = test.length; j < len; j++) {
    $('td:nth-child(' + test[j] + ')').hide();
  }

});
```

```css
body{font-family:calibri;}
  table { padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
  table thead td { background-color: #f2f2f2; font-weight:bold;}
  table td { border: 1px solid #d7d7d7; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="myOptions" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">
  <option value="1">Name</option>
  <option value="2">Address</option>
  <option value="3">City</option>
  <option value="4">Country</option>
</select>  
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headercell">
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>Country</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="datacell">
      <td>Anand</td>
      <td>2404/71</td>
      <td>Mohali</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="datacell">
      <td>Nilesh</td>
      <td>236/10</td>
      <td>Chandigarh</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="datacell">
      <td>Rahul</td>
      <td>A 71 Radhepuri</td>
      <td>New Delhi</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pratius</td>
      <td>Trishna Apartment-740</td>
      <td>Hydrabad</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Here is my updated code https://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/od1atnc3/

Comment: Nice programming.  Could you mark mine as solution? It would help a lot.  But, if it didn't help you, don't feel pressured to.